# Unable to create an index. Get 'relation already exists' error

Tags: python, postgresql

I get this error message when I try to create an index on a table. The schema of the table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE object(
     id int, 
     id_obj int,
     id_parent int        
 )
```

So, when I do (in Python code):

```
cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX id_idx ON object(id)')
# or
cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX id_obj_idx ON object(id_obj)')
```

I get these error messages:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "id_idx" already exists
# or
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "id_obj_idx" already exists
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe you already defined the index?

Comment: No, I run these queries - `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` - in sequence, one by one.

Comment: I see, what I did wrong. In fact I defined an index with the same name, but on another table. This peculiarity seems to differ postgres from databases like MySQL or MSSQL

Comment: I do not believe it is a peculiarity. If you name it, the computer can only assume that you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Incognos Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How can a computer "assume" anything?

Comment: @Jacobian it means that a computer will only do as it is told and will never try to guess at what you are trying to do. If you try to create things with the same name, whether classes, databases, indexes, files, etc... the computer will likely either erase the existing one or give you an error. Therefore, it is not a peculiarity, just the way it works, unless there is specific code written to deal with such instances. Ergo, computers are only as smart as their programmers...

Comment: I think you took my word "peculiarity" out of the context. By that word I only mean that postgresql differs from databases like mysql or mssql (or sqlite etc). By this I do not mean that it is rather strange or bad or something like that.

Comment: "Ergo, computers are only as smart as their programmers..." Sometimes, I think that smart phones are much smarter than blonde ladies, who own them =) Sorry for sexism - it's just a joke and in fact I do not think so =)